# How to change laravel email auth to phone auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am new in laravel and using laravel 8. I used laravel jetsteam for auth setup and it's working fine but I want to use phone auth instead of email auth. How can I do it ?

Comment: Sounds as freelance project, not a question ..

Comment: Hi @Svetoslav, I am not asking to do it, I just want to know where to start from or if is it even possible by modifying jetstream or should i start from scratch without jetstream.

Comment: You want to use `phone number` as username, i stead of `email`. Right?

Comment: You can use [Twilo Verify](https://www.twilio.com/blog/verify-phone-numbers-php-laravel-application-twilio-verify)

Comment: @PorushManjhi By default everything is possible so you can make it with or without Jetstream. But you need to research a little bit for "Laravel Phone Auth" or something similar over the net > after that as other mentioned you can search for Twilo Laravel and etc.. 
This way you will find already made solutions easy to be integrated + you can than think if it is possible to add it to your Jetstream site or you have to make it clean Laravel..

Comment: Hi @HarshitMahajan, I am using a different sms gateway that's cheaper than twilo.

Comment: @Svetoslav, I already searched around but didn't find anything other than twilio. I am thinking of removing jetstream and start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

As long you are using Jetstream you are also surely use Fortify.
Fortify has the ability to customize the Authentication...

[Fortify README](https://github.com/laravel/fortify#customizing-user-authentication)

```
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if ($user &&
        Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        return $user;
    }
});
```